# Angular: Why is ViewChild with QueryList returning only the first instance?

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have an Angular component called `Component1`. It contains several nested instances of the same component, like this:

```html
<div>
  <ng-container *ngFor='let item of items'>
    <component-1>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

All 5 items in `items` are being displayed, so I know they're there. However, when I try to retrieve an array containing all 5 instances of `Component1` like this:

```js
@ViewChild(Component1) children: QueryList<Component1>;
```

then `children`, instead of containing an array of `Component1`s, contains only one `Component1`: the first of the 5.

Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: did you succeed with this

Answer (score 10):

You will need to use [@ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren)

> Use to get the QueryList of elements or directives from the view DOM. Any time a child element is added, removed, or moved, the query list will be updated, and the changes observable of the query list will emit a new value.

```js
@ViewChildren(Component1) children: QueryList<Component1>;
```

---

`ViewChild` only returns the first item.

> Property decorator that configures a view query. The change detector looks for the first element or the directive matching the selector in the view DOM.